# Javascript: Two radio radio checks

Tags: javascript

I have a short form with two questions and two radio buttons (answers Yes and No) for the first question. I wrote this JS code to disable the answers on the second question if someone checks "No" on the first. This code works.
But then if I change my mind and check Yes still on the first question, the options for the second question remain disabled.

I would like to get to a situation where that second question would be possible to answer if someone decided to change their mind and clicked Yes after initially clicking No.

Cloud you please help me with coming up with a solution to this problem?

```
var input = document.getElementById("jump-question"); 

function myFunction() {
if (input.checked == true){
alert("working")
document.getElementById("question-disable").setAttribute("disabled", true);
}
  }
```

Comment: Enable them if `input.checked` isn't `true` :) Is there anything you're having trouble with?

Comment: `setAttribute("disabled", input.checked)` …? (Without restricting it inside that if condition, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

With plain js, you have to write some boilerplate to get it working. Does the below snippet help you at all?

```js
function updateSecondQuestion() {
  var radios = document.radioForm.secondQuestion;
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    radios[i].disabled = document.radioForm.firstQuestion["value"] == "no";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="radioForm">
  <div>
    <p>First question?</p>
    Yes<input type="radio" onchange="updateSecondQuestion()" name="firstQuestion" value="yes" /> 
    No <input type="radio" onchange="updateSecondQuestion()" name="firstQuestion" value="no" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Second question?</p>
    Yes <input type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="yes" /> 
    No <input type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="no" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Nice and clean example!